# C++ Singelton Class Vs Namespaces Vs Public Static Variables

Tags: c++, static, namespaces, tcl, bison

Which of the following approches is best to define a global variable:

1. public static class variables
2. use single object of the class with all private variables: ( singleton class )
3. namespaces - should i just use a namespace instead.

I am not sure if the question even makes sense. Just trying to find the best practice.

The code below is not syntactically correct but I think it should convey the idea:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
class Reader {
  Reader();
  Library* lib;
  static Reader* reader;
public:
  Reader* Instance () {
      if (!reader) { reader = new Reader() }
      return reader;
  }
  void setLibrary ( Library* ptr ) { lib = ptr }
  Library* getLibrary { return lib }
}

Reader* Reader::reader = NULL;

int main( ) {
  ...
  Library* lib = new Library("test");
  Reader::Instance()->setLibrary(lib);
  Reader::Instance()->getLibrary()->addCell("AND2X1");
 }

   -------------- OR -------------

class Reader {
   Reader();
public:
  static Library* lib;
}

Library* Reader::lib = NULL;

int main( ) {
  ...
  Reader::lib = new Library("test");
  Reader::lib->addCell("AND2X1");
 }

    ---------------- OR -----------------

namespace Reader {
   Library* lib = NULL;
}

int main( ) {
  ...
  Reader::lib = new Library("test");
  Reader::lib->addCell("AND2X1");
}
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am trying to created new commands in my C++ program with a TCL frontend using Tcl_createCommand. I cannot pass any new arguments to the function implementation
as a result I need global variables to access some of my data inside the function.
All the solution I found for this seem to be using global varaibles.

The other instance where I need the above is when using bison to generate a parser. 
I need to define global variables to perform actions when using bison grammar.

Comment: noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo . . .

Comment: You're asking the wrong question, about the _worst_ practice. Use `clientData` as CodeChords says.

Comment: [C++ FQA](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/global-vars.html) [27.15] What's a good coding standard for using global variables? Here's the ideal way to declare a global variable: `// int xyz;    ←the thing that makes this global ideal is the leading //`
as in, don't use global variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prototype of the create command is:

```
Tcl_Command Tcl_CreateCommand(interp, cmdName, proc, clientData, deleteProc)
```

The `clientData` allows you to associate data with the command. You can then use the data you need, no globals at all!

BTW, you might want to add `tcl` tag to this question :-)

Comment: Thanks CodeChords, that was really helpful.

Comment: One more thing I wanted to add was I have the same issue when using bison. Is there something I can do for Bison files instead of defining global variables?

Comment: `ClientData` is a `void *` (i.e., one-word-sized pointer) with the guarantee that Tcl won't peek inside it or cast it to anything; it will get passed to the `proc` callback with no interpretation being applied to it at all. When integrating with C++ methods, that's where you pass `this` through (possibly with extra wrapping).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a global singleton (which you should not want to do! but they are helpful sometimes), the C++ FAQ has a decent answer.

Basically:

```
class Foo_class {
  public:
  class bar {
    public:
    int x;
  };

  int x;
  Foo_class() { x = 2; mybar = new bar(); } // This constructor will be called on first reference to the singleton
  void set_bar(bar* what) { mybar = what; }

  bar *mybar;
};

Foo_class& Foo()
{
  static Foo_class *myclass = new Foo_class();
  return *myclass;
}

int main(void)
{
  typedef Foo_class::bar foobar;
  foobar hmph;
  hmph.x = 70;
  Foo().set_bar(hmph);
  foo().x = 7;
}
```

Comment: Is using a Singleton the best approach among the three above?

Comment: @balajikommineni It depends on a lot of things. If you're a fan of RAII, the global singleton would be good, assuming you don't have cyclic global singleton dependencies. There is a lot of debate about which strategy is right, but if you ask me, the real question is: are you only going to have one Reader? That's kind of the point of a singleton, generally. Only having one, single, controlled point of access to a class. That can be really handy like in your example. If you don't want/need that though, consider other options and go with what works. Maybe readability is important, etc...